# How will I update the edited object values back to json url?

Tags: jquery, html, json, http-post

This is my array of objects stored in myjsonarray.json url. I am able to modify the data by calling the json object on html but i am stuck with storing back the updated key values back to url. example by changing the key name from niki to roddy. how will i do that guys?

{

```
"justin": [
    { "name": "niki", "age": 31},
    { "name": "balu", "age": 35}
],
"recent": [
    { "name": "vinoth", "age": 31},
    { "name": "gopal", "age": 35}
],
"old": [
    { "name": "geetha", "age": 31},
    { "name": "nanju", "age": 35}
]
```

}

This is my jquery code for editing the jquery data
$(".jsonDataPost").click(function(){

```
          $.post("jsonFile/json_ArrayData.json",function(data){

           $.each(data.justin, function(key,value) {
           data.justin[key].name = 'roddy';




    });
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't update the data with JS like that. "Large" answer: If you want to edit a file, like "myjsonarray.json" you need a server-side script, JavaScript is a client-side script primary (now, it have the option to be a server-side because of frameworks like NodeJS or others). You can do an array generating the new JSON and then, send that array with an AJAX request to the server-side, and the server-side then, modify the file. PHP, NodeJS, Python, and many others are server-side.

Comment: Yes Asfo. I understood well about how to handle json file from your explanation. Thankyou..!

Answer (score 0):

In short answer is you can't save in a file using client size script, you have to use some server side scripting like `PHP`, `NodeJS` etc. to save something in a file.

If you have `PHP` you can post updated data to server, and in server side you can rewrite your json file.

And in `NodeJs` you can read your json file, and can modify whatever you read and then write back to file

Comment: Akshay thanx for your answer... I am now clear after your explanation...